# How to install android sdk tools when there is no the Launch Standalone SDK Manager

Tags: android-studio, sdk

How to download sdk tools in android studio 3.0.1 for example Documentation for Android SDK in Android Studio 3.0.1 there is no more the ability of Launch Standalone SDK Manager

Answer (score 0):

First click on the SDK manager icon at the top as follows:

[image]

... and then click on the "SDK Tools" tab, and optionally click on the "Show Package Details" checkbox towards the bottom of the dialog to see the versioning for each tool as follows:

[image]

... and then checkmark the tools you'd like to install by clicking on "Apply" and then "OK".